# Mysql syntax error with trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision AFTER UPDATE ON players BEGIN 
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'collision') FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y; 
END;
```

mysql 5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (Ubuntu)

But I am getting a syntax error, and I don't see where...

EDIT:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision AFTER UPDATE ON players BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'collision') FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y; END//
DELIMITER ;
```

This is still getting a syntax error...

[image]

This is getting a syntax error:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision AFTER UPDATE ON players
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (SELECT count(*) FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y)>0 THEN 
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Collision detected'; 
        END IF; 
    END;// 
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Comment: You probably didn't change `DELIMITER`.

Comment: @omega: Post the entire syntax error message. Unless which, we too don't see where ... !!!???

Comment: I put the image of it, but its not that helpful...

Comment: if I put "for each row" before the "before", then it says `ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`.

Comment: It is obvious. Triggers are not regular routines. They are for background action. You can't expect them to return a cursor or any other result. But perform an action like setting or resetting a value in a row or any dml operation on other related table, etc.

Comment: How do I get it to roll back the change if there is a collision then?

Comment: Remove `BEGIN` after `ON PLAYERS`. It is the error and also redundant.

Comment: I did that, but still get a syntax error, I put the image above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't change `DELIMITER`

> How do I do that?

With the `DELIMITER` command, described here

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html

It's important to change the delimiter when you're creating triggers or procedures, because otherwise using the semicolon statement delimiter inside the body of your trigger (e.g. at the end of the SELECT statement) is ambiguous with respect to the semicolon at the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

This is a very common source of confusion for MySQL developers.

Comment: ok I added my new code above with delimeter, but its still getting syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**:

> *How do I get it to roll back the change if there is a collision then*

`Rollback`, `commit` are not allowed in triggers.
Instead, you can raise a `signal` by setting specific `sqlstate` on a condition failure.

```
IF ( condition_for_collision_true ) THEN
  SET error_message = 'Invalid XYZ'; -- set proper message

  -- set proper error state number
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE <ERROR_STATE_NUMBER> SET message_text = error_message;
END IF;
```

This causes the transaction be aborted.

---

**Original answer**:

Triggers get fired for each row affected.

And you are missing the same in your trigger definition.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER checkcollision 
       AFTER UPDATE ON players 
       FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'collision') FROM walls WHERE NEW.x=x AND NEW.y=y; 
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

And, it is obvious. Triggers are not regular routines. They are for background action. You can't expect them to return a cursor or any other result. But perform an action like setting or resetting a value in a row or any DML operation on other related table, etc.

Change the body accordingly.

Comment: Does this with with mysql 5.1, I don't think it does.

Comment: Yes. Conditional transaction abortion only possible since `MySQL 5.5`. A hack is suggested [*here*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html#c8808).